# When using https but not DNSSEC, under what situation, a client is vulnerable?

Tags: https, certificate, dnssec

So DNSSEC is to ensure that returned IP address is not poisoned. 
And https is to verify the remote server.

My question is that when protected by https, under what circumstances, a client is vulnerable?

Say I go to https://www.facebook.com, even if I'm not protected by DNSSEC, what damage can an adversary cause? 
Let's assume no DigiNotar stuffs.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps better suited to [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @lsowen New to stackoverflow... will ask there, thanks